# iPhone is not available. Please reconnect the device

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm on iOS 13.5 and using Xcode 11.4 to build on to it. I'm getting this error message:

[image]

The `KBlackberry` is my iPhone device name.

I tried restarting the device and reconnecting of course and various other things but nothing seems to fix it. My next step is to try a newer version of Xcode.

Comment: Have you try quitting Xcode and restart again

Comment: Yeah tried that but getting same error

Comment: DOwnload Support file from here for 13.5 https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport

Comment: After installing the support file I had to unplug and plug the device and do a clean build (clear derived data and cache in Xcode) to get it to work.

Comment: Xcode 11.7 → iOS 13.7

Comment: it works after update the ios version.

Comment: I am facing same issue with iOS  13.6.1 ad xcode 11.7

Comment: Same with 12.2 & iOS14.1

Comment: I just needed an updated version of xcode due to lack of appropriate support files

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Xcode 11.4 includes SDKs for iOS 13.4 as mentioned on the release notes
[here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_release_notes).

You must update to the beta version if you wish to deal with iOS 13.5.

Comment: Yes that was it. I had to install Xcode 11.5 beta 2 to get it running. This error message I was having is way too confusing for something simple like this. I think it'd be good to keep this question up to help others seeing the same error

Comment: If cleaning the build folder doesn't work, you can follow this other answer which details how to force unpair the device (and also actually see if it's "ready for development"!): https://stackoverflow.com/a/62619030/5974754

Comment: I wonder how I didn't understand it. It was so clear from the error message...

Answer (score 344):

Before you debug with iPhone, follow this mapping table about the version of Xcode and iOS：

Xcode 12.3 → iOS 14.3

Xcode 12.2 → iOS 14.2

Xcode 12.1 → iOS 14.1

Xcode 12 → iOS 14

Xcode 11.7 → iOS 13.7

Xcode 11.6 → iOS 13.6

Xcode 11.5 → iOS 13.5

Xcode 11.4 → iOS 13.4

Download at https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.

If you're still encountering the error, try to unpair the device within the menu Window > Devices and Simulators, clean Xcode, reconnect and trust the device, then re-run. It worked for me!
[image]

Get more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode

Comment: This was useful after upgrading to 11.5. Thanks!

Comment: Unpairing worked for me to get Xcode 11.6 -> iOS 13.5.1

Comment: Devices can be found under Window -> Devices and Simulators OR Shift + CMD + 2.

But this didn't worked out for me. The last step which is missing in this answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63556220/12035498)

Comment: weird i have 2 phones both with 13.6.1 and Xcode 13.7, it works on one and doesn't on the other

Comment: I'm speechless that Xcode 11.7 cannot debug a 13.6 phone.

Comment: Even worse, olivaresF - Xcode 11.7 worked with my 13.6 phone yesterday, but not today!

Comment: Xcode 11.7 doesn't work with my 13.6.1 phone, wondering if the point release cause the failure

Comment: Worked for me. Xcode version 11.7 iphone 13.6.1 previous to upgrade. Somewhat suspicious way of enforcing COVID19 tracking upgrade.

Comment: Same here @olivaresF I'm not able to debug 13.6 iPad on Xcode 11.7, have to upgrade it to 13.7 to not get this error

Comment: Couldn't build for my iPhone on iOS 14, thanks for this tip! Why would apple wait to release Xcode after iOS 14 !?

Comment: unpair is great. worked with Xcode 11.7 > iOS 13.6.1

Comment: I also had to restart my device before re-pairing

Comment: This fixed my issue with xcode 11.7 -> 13.6 iPad... https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659166

Comment: This is also happening on XCode 12.1. iOS 14 which is mindblowing..

Comment: I was using Xcode 12 so I updated to 12.2 beta and ran it and it worked fine. Then went back and ran Xcode 12 and now 12 works fine.

Comment: How come the 12.2 Xcode is a beta but the iOS 12.2 is not. This is total garbage.

Comment: So don't set your iPad or iPhone to automatic update for the iOS... mine just updated from iOS 14.1 to 14.2 and the Xcode 12.1 stopped working with it and now I have to wait for an hour to upgrade my Xcode from 12.1 to 12.2 as well. It is not a 500MB type of upgrade. It is downloading a whopping 11GB

Comment: iOS 14 device, updated xcode to version 12.2, which required 40gig of free space, I deleted the existing xcode install, then it still showed the same error until i unpaired it as explained above, from that point the app installed successfully

Comment: iPad Updated while I was asleep. Bought a macbook air that is too small as Xcode takes up majority of the space. Damn you apple..

Comment: This table does not seem correct. Till yesterday I was installing my apps on iOS 14.3 using Xcode 12.2

Comment: I had this problem with xcode 12.1 ios 14.1. I did all the above. Still didn't work. Then I turned off my iphone and then turned on again. I could see in Window/device and simulators in Xcode my iphone being prepared for development (in the top bar). After that, everything worked.

Answer (score 65):

Developers who are using Xcode 11.5 and trying to install their app in iOS 13.6 device will also see this message. It's a very confusing message.

All you need to do is **Download Device support files of iOS 13.6** from this link

[filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport)

- Close Xcode
- Unzip and *paste* it in this location:

  **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/**
- Reopen Xcode.

Now you can install the app on the iOS 13.6 device using Xcode 11.5.

Comment: Thanks! This was the last step, working now with iOS14

Comment: I doesn't work for me having trouble with XCode 11.5 and iOS 13.7. Finally, I have to install XCode 11.7 (though it's not officially supported on macOS 10.15.4).

Comment: Easy and elegant! Worked for me with Xcode 11.5 and iOS 13.6.1

Comment: This should be the solution if you don't want to use an Xcode beta version

Comment: This worked but I had to unpair device from devices and simulator also. But don't know app is installing after a considerable amount of time. I m using Xcode 12.1 and iOS 14.5.1

Comment: If not works, try unpair the device and reconnect.

Answer (score 51):

Well, to be able to even get some information about why this happens, I did this:

1. Open Xcode
2. Go to *windows* → *Devices and Simulators*
3. Select your phone on the left
4. Scroll down on the right side and see the error
5. [image]
6. Update to latest Xcode version
7. Update you phone to the latest iOS
8. Unpair your phone from *windows* → *Devices and Simulators*.
9. Pair your iPhone
10. Enjoy

Comment: This is my solution. Any reason why a *new* version of xcode can't handle an *older* version of iOS? Like one minor version older...

Comment: it is not back-compatible for some strange reason. Ever since they forced the ios 13 SDK this kind of stuff has happened. I have no idea if that has any connection, but I feel like it has and glad it helped you

Comment: First step for Apple would be to add a "Show Devices and Simulators" button to that dialog. Better yet, append the log from that tool to the error message.

Comment: These things only happen when one is under deadline.

Answer (score 37):

**Going to Window → Devices and Simulators will give you a better idea of what's going on.** In my case, I had to update the iPhone since Xcode updated overnight and stopped supporting my iPhone.

[image]

Comment: Hey Zorayr, did you fix it?  I am having the same issue, but as far as I understand Xcode above 11.7 is beta still...

Comment: Just need to make sure Xcode is matching iOS version. In my case, I just had to update the iPhone and it worked.

Comment: I got this because I'm running a beta version that isn't supported by the current App Store release of Xcode

Answer (score 21):

### Follow these steps:

1. Check your iOS Version from (*Settings* → *General* → *About* → *Software Version*) and get the device support file from the link below:

   https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport
2. Next, unzip the files and place them at the following location:

   *Applications* → *Xcode* → right click → *Show Package Contents* → *Contents* → *Developer* → *Platforms* → *iPhoneOS.platform* → *DeviceSupport*
3. **Restart your Macbook or pc **

after restarting xcode will configuring and ready to install your app app in your iPhone which is running on higher ios version.

Answer (score 18):

Xcode 11.4 does not support the new iOS 13.5. **Updating to Xcode 11.5 fixed the issue for me**

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_release_notes

> Known Issues
> Xcode 11.4 doesn’t work with devices running iOS 13.4 beta 1 and beta 2. (60055806)

Comment: This appears to be it, I’m updating XCode now. I was on XCode 11.4.1 with a real iPhone on iOS 13.5.1.

Answer (score 12):

If you are on iOS 13.5 and Xcode 11.5, removing the device and adding it again fixed it for me.

Comment: Remove from what? Physically unplug it? Remove it from some list of devices within XCode?

Comment: @JCutting8 that's what I did, and also cleaned it before plugging my iPad again.

Comment: The unpair turned out to be successful for XCode 12 and IOS 13.7.

Answer (score 12):

Restarting the iPhone helped me.

Comment: Same for me on iPad.

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Answer (score 10):

If your iPhone iOS version is later than Xcode device support, you should download the files device support from [this site](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport) and then paste at the below location:

```
/Applications/Xcode11_4_1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/13.5
```

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue today.  *[device name] is not available.  Please reconnect the device.*

My iPhone is running iOS 13.6.1, and the latest version of Xcode will not build with that.  I saw a comment on the Apple Developer forums [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659388) to update the phone to iOS 13.7, and that resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using an old Xcode version and your phone is updated, you don't need to update your Xcode. You can simply add the device support.

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport

Answer (score 7):

Whenever this error occurs, either your Xcode version or iPhone version isn't working together. You will have to update one or the either or both.

2020 Update: Xcode: 12 Beta for iOS 14

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if covered in previous answers, but if you go to:

Xcode menu → *Window* → *Devices and Simulators*

You can see warnings and error messages for the device. For example, mine is below... I just updated everything, so I will need to workout where to go from here.

"The current device configuration is unsupported. This iPhone 11 is running iOS 13.6.1 (17G…"

"To run on this device, please update to a version of Xcode that supports iOS 13.6.1. You can download Xcode from the Mac App Store or the Apple Developer website."

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue... Xcode 11.5 iOS 13.5 hadn't yet found a fix... so I just switched to build over Wi-Fi ...

Here are some simple instructions on how to get that setup: *[Wireless debugging for iOS](https://codeburst.io/wireless-debugging-ios-run-debug-install-builds-over-wifi-a48fc49ac3a7)*.

Answer (score 5):

If you are connecting it with a cable, clean the build folder, run it on the simulator, and then run it again immediately on your phone.

If you are using it without a cable, make sure the Wi-Fi connection is exactly the same on both your PC and your phone or turn the personal hotspot on your phone and connect your PC to the hotspot to make sure they're using the exact same connection.

Comment: It sounds like of "sick-and-wrong" yet elegant, all at once, but I believe you. (This is a device that can happily be on local wifi while hotspotting other devices on BT, WIFI or UBS to your carrier network, at the same time).

Answer (score 5):

So I guess all roads lead to Rome. If you're using Xcode 11.7 together with iOS 13.6, consider updating your iOS to 13.7. That worked for me. There isn't any need to upgrade Xcode to 12.

Answer (score 4):

Download the support file for the iOS version of your device from this link and follow the instructions.

[Link to the GitHub](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport)

Answer (score 4):

My experience, *yesterday* my iOS `13.6` is supported by Xcode `11.7` and now today the Xcode rejected my iPhone and I update the Xcode to version `12` and everything get back on track.

**Solution**:

```
Update your Xcode to the latest version.
```

**Hint**: *there is no need to update iOS.*

Answer (score 3):

Restarting my Mac was the only thing that resolved the problem.

Other things I tried before restarting which didn't work:

- Restarting Xcode.
- Re-attaching the iPhone.
- Restarting the iPhone.

I am also now using *wireless debugging* after reading [DanielSmurts' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863826/iphone-is-not-available-please-reconnect-the-device/62015438#62015438).

Comment: I also recoomend using https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport. But indeed, to me only restarting worked.

Answer (score 2):

I am now using Xcode 11.6, macOS 10.15.6, and iOS 13.5.1.

First the problem was that I was on Xcode 11.4. But I couldn't upgrade since I wasn't on macOS v10.15 (Catalina) yet. (And I couldn't upgrade because my RAID went down and I couldn't make a backup, but that's another saga.)

After upgrading to Catalina, then to Xcode 11.6 I still couldn't build to the device. So I opened *Devices and Simulators* and unpaired the phone, as mentioned in the comments here. Then when I tried to re-pair, a warning message said that the device was busy (it was not). Finally, after rebooting the phone (had to untether it for it to come back on), cleaning Xcode, and re-pairing the phone, I finally, finally built to the device. So good luck!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

For me it works to unpair the iPhone.

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Answer (score 2):

This means the **Xcode you are using is not compatible with the iOS version on the device**. (*You have updated iOS on the device, but have not updated Xcode.*)

Open the **App Store** app and update Xcode.

If there aren't any updates - go [**here**](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=Xcode) and download the latest version (not beta) of Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Please download the latest device from this URL and add to devices.

https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/

Answer (score 1):

If you need to stay on Xcode 11.4, try this:

1. Install Xcode 11.5 (with [`xcodes`](https://github.com/RobotsAndPencils/xcodes) for example);
2. Copy `/Applications/Xcode-11.5.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/13.5` to `/Applications/Xcode-11.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/13.5`;
3. Select Xcode 11.5, build a dummy sample app and start it with your iOS 13.5;
4. Kill Xcode 11.5 and switch back to Xcode 11.4.

You should now be able to run your app on iOS 13.5 with Xcode 11.4.

Answer (score 1):

Steps I used to fix it:

1. Updated macOS to 10.15.5.
2. Updated Xcode to 11.5

It still showed the same error so,

3. I disconnected the iPhone and reconnected again.
4. Removed Apple ID and added Apple ID again.

And it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that your phone's iOS version is not supported by your Xcode version. You can verify this by "Adding Additional Simulators", tapping the **+** sign at the bottom left of that dialog, and then selecting "Download more simulator runtimes..." in the **OS Version** field. Compare the most recent available **OS Version** to your phone's iOS version (on your phone go to *Settings* -> *General* -> *About*).

Upgrading Xcode fixes this - so long as that doesn't cause any problems for you. If for some reason you need to stay on the same Xcode version but still need to support a newer iOS version, check this article out: https://davidlaristudios.com/2016/11/adding-device-support-to-xcode/

You can actually copy the device support out of a newer Xcode version and paste it into your Xcode version. Note that this requires that you download the new Xcode version separately - don't upgrade your current version. You can download the newer Xcode version directly from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Xcode 11.6 and iOS 13.6. Unpairing the device and adding it again solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Xcode beta 3 (the latest at the time of writing) and encountered this issue with an [iPhone XS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_XS) running the latest iOS 14 Beta.

The solution, after trying a lot of suggestions, was to restart my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I am using an iPhone SE iOS 13.6.1 and Xcode 13.5 and I faced the same issue. While the `iPhone is not available. Please reconnect the device` warning window is open, I turned off the iPhone, reopened and rebuilt the Xcode project, `Trust`ed in the iPhone and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

After trying all of the previous answers, the only thing that worked for me iOS 14.2 was to run Xcode 12.2 beta, and then switch back to Xcode 12.0.1 production.

Answer (score 1):

If the Xcode version you're using supports the *major* iOS version you're targeting, there's a workaround. Let's say you have installed Xcode `12.1.0` and you wish to run your project on a device with iOS `14.2`.

Then, you can download the `iOS Developer Disk Image` from [here](https://github.com/mspvirajpatel/Xcode_Developer_Disk_Images/releases) and move it from the downloads folder to `/Applications/Xcode_12.1.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`

You'd download `iOS 14.2 Developer Disk Image` and extract the contents of `14.2.zip` to your Xcode's `DeviceSupport` directory.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, switching USB ports worked for me. I tried many of the above solutions - updating, etc. Nothing worked until I switched to a different USB port. Strange!

Answer (score 0):

in iOS 17.4 and Xcode 15.2

1. goto Window > Devices and Simulators
2. replug your device
3. choose trust in your device
4. run your app