# Target is not found, Please reconnect the device, Xcode:Device Support File

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, swiftui

After upgrading Xcode I can not run my iPhone on the Xcode.

My Xcode waiting and waiting finally give an error like that and it stuck.
Even though I unplugged the USB cable and delete derived data nothing changed.

I faced the same problem with upgrade Xcode to 12.0 12.1 and 12.2.
Is there anything missing? What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: I always have a clean install of Xcode instead of upgrading Xcode directly from App Store, to clean up the cache and old support files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iPhone is not available. Please reconnect the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863826/iphone-is-not-available-please-reconnect-the-device)

Comment: similar but i can not say as an answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Go to my Github repo for **14.2** [click here to download the iOS 14.2 file](https://github.com/seyitcodeit/14.2.git) or for **14.3** here [14.3](https://github.com/seyitcodeit/DeviceSupportFile_14.3.git)
- Unzip ,copy and paste the file which you downloaded from repo to this path :

`Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`

- Restart the Xcode

That's all. You can build and go on your project.

Any comment for feedback will be appreciated  :)

**Visually solution :**

Step 1 : Right Click Xcode and show package contents then follow the pictures below
[image]
Step 2
[image]
Step 3:
[image]
Step 4: Here is Device Support Files Folder
[image]
Step 5: Put here file here and restart the Xcode if it is open
[image]

---

Finally, Just in case it is a good idea delete derived data, press at the same time 4 keys like:

**command + option + Shift + K** (delete derived data shortcut)

Comment: Having the same problem too. It used to work for on XCode 12.2 and iOS 14.2 and then just suddenly stopped. I get "Failed to prepare the device for development" in Devices window. Unpairing didn't help. I think I'm reinstalling the XCode the 5th time during the same month.. Can't wait for 2020 to end

Comment: @ErikPeruzzi You need clean the build, delete derived data and then run a fresh one. It'll work

Answer (score 3):

I did not try the solution above, but I had the exact same issue and as for me, all I needed to do is the following:

Go go to Devices and Simulators (CMD + Shift + 2) or by clicking Window and Devices and Simulator, find the device and right click to unpair it, and disconnect physically the device from your computer.

[image: Xcode Unpair Device]

Then while unpaired, restart Xcode and connect the device back again.

And then it worked for me :). But I do believe a solution proposed by [zeytin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14531220/zeytin) might be necessary if what helped me fails.