# Swift Xcode can't connect device

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, macos, device

We started a swift project in Xcode. When would like to test our code on a real iPhone, but it doesn't find the device. We can't select the device.
Has someone an idea?
Thank you!

Comment: Is the Xcode version "compatible" with the iOS version of the device? Also, is your phone "charging" (no issue with the connection)? Is the phone registered as developers one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64854525/14531220 try this one

Answer (score 0):

1-Select Window ➜ Organizer in Xcode. Now under Devices, select your device. If it is not ready for development then click use for development.

2-If above doesn't solve your problem then from your project settings, set deployment target to one which your app is developed for or lesser.

3-Otherwise there is some issue with certificates and provisioning profiles. Make sure your device's UDID is added in the provisioning profile you are using.

source = Dovydas Šopa